# PHP Parsing object(stdClass) Response

Tags: php, parsing

I'm working with a wsdl file, and learning quite a lot from the whole process.

I'm instantiating the SoapClient:

```
$webservice = new SoapClient("mainwsdl.wsdl");
var_dump($webservice->AccountsGetXML());
```

Below is the response, and I'm still a little new with parsing data.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["AccountsGetXMLResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["any"]=>
    string(391) "<AccountsWSDS xmlns=""><ERRORS><ERROR_ID>1</ERROR_ID><TABLE_NAME>Accounts</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_ID>NoID</TABLE_ID><ROW_ID>-1</ROW_ID><COLUMN_ID>EXCEPTION</COLUMN_ID><ERROR_TYPE>E</ERROR_TYPE><ERROR_CODE>0</ERROR_CODE><ERROR_TEXT>Error connecting to database - please contact ABC Customer Services.  Msg: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</ERROR_TEXT></ERRORS></AccountsWSDS>"
  }
  ["rowCount"]=>
  NULL
  ["pageCount"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I haven't played with object(stdClass) responses before.  Or if I have I've been oblivious to it.

I figure I need to parse ["AccountsGetXMLResult"] for specific information, but also ["rowCount"] and ["pageCount"].

I'm confused what the #2 (3) is all about.

Anyway, here's my attempt at parsing the data.  I started with the AccountsGetXMLResult:

```
echo $webservice->AccountsGetXMLResult;
```

Here's what I got back.
**PHP Notice:  Undefined property: SoapClient::$AccountsGetXMLResult in /apache/test.php on line 23**

So clearly I'm in need of help with dissecting responses.

Comment: The `#2 (3)` means that it's the second instance of `stdClass` for that process and that there are three properties of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$webservice->AccountsGetXML()` *returns* an object of type `stdClass` with the properties you see in the var dump. `stdClass` is just an "empty placeholder class" without any predefined properties or methods of its own. To access the properties you see, work on the *return value* of `$webservice->AccountsGetXML()`:

```
$obj = $webservice->AccountsGetXML();
var_dump($obj->AccountsGetXMLResult);
var_dump($obj->AccountsGetXMLResult->any);
```

This also works like this:

```
echo $webservice->AccountsGetXML()->AccountsGetXMLResult->any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($webservice->AccountsGetXML()->AccountsGetXMLResult->any)),TRUE);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: I know he isn't using JSOn, this just converts the response to JSOn then immediately converts it back to a PHP array allowing him to access it as a PHP array. It works.

Comment: @ClintDecker Hey man this worked great for me. Nothing else seems to be working. It converts the SOAP XML perfectly into a PHP array, so thanks!